# How can there be two different PUBLIC KEY BLOCKs of the same key?

Tags: public-key, pgp, dataformat

The key at pgp.mit.edu is:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: SKS 1.1.6
Comment: Hostname: pgp.mit.edu

mQENBE/JeVIBCACppoOlVmInMGHOa+k/v0XL71V2fcfni0xjQ8tLwbP+XUTlkmtLLbrExSms
O1ZC9FWujXJLi297k26uB9DsJ7B/Xl2L3ERyMy8cnyUEjSHeV7Ryb35bUqHmFzYxSKsgMk1X
zFGaSvIGYeN10vsMngWL1rt6ggdDcPRpy1gO0m8sBPoTXaGtq6vn2DxXCc1Qt0XiQRpYou7w
dGnLtpl8BqRgr608v9n0ZIWWEHjGtzCCInIvz0owS+Fp5kJJxMtnQEEMY7trvkk86HOarKHf
viFZLyjWXO902UnWNiUwBSg1oPbAGe4hwcnGRYnOL5jhgdBUo9QP5f/AjIRctqejv8QdABEB
AAG0L25vdHBsYXRvIChCaXRDb2luIElEKSA8ZHNjb3Rlc2VAbGl0bW9jcmFjeS5jb20+iQE [SNIP] c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=BQpG
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

The key I exported from my Kleopatra certificate store on Windows is:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v2

mQENBE/JeVIBCACppoOlVmInMGHOa+k/v0XL71V2fcfni0xjQ8tLwbP+XUTlkmtL
LbrExSmsO1ZC9FWujXJLi297k26uB9DsJ7B/Xl2L3ERyMy8cnyUEjSHeV7Ryb35b
UqHmFzYxSKsgMk1XzFGaSvIGYeN10vsMngWL1rt6ggdDcPRpy1gO0m8sBPoTXaGt
q6vn2DxXCc1Qt0XiQRpYou7wdGnLtpl8BqRgr608v9n0ZIWWEHjGtzCCInIvz0ow
S+Fp5kJJxMtnQEEMY7trvkk86HOarKHfviFZLyjWXO902UnWNiUwBSg1oPbAGe4h
wcnGRYnOL5jhgdBUo9QP5f/AjIRctqejv8QdABEBAAG0L25vdHBsYXRvIChCaXRD
b2luIElEKSA8ZHNjb3Rlc2VAbGl0bW9jcmFjeS5jb20+iQE [SNIP] 4BBMBAgAiBQJPyXlS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=aSDt
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

When I import either one, Kleopatra says "Keys found: 1, Keys imported: 0, Keys unchanged: 1"  Clearly the two keys are the same, but the content (where I indicated with `[SNIP]`) differs.

Comment: This isn't a programming question and thus is off-topic. It belongs on [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or superuser, where it's [already answered](https://superuser.com/questions/696941/human-readable-dump-of-gpg-public-key)

Comment: Sorry, the question is actually answered [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/150942/662) on Security.

Comment: Thanks!  Should we close it or delete it?  I searched superuser (not security though) for it and didn't find it, so I guess close is better.